# Run View listener callback code in asynctask thread Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask, callback

I run the following code in an asynctask. For some reason, though, the onGlobalLayout code is run in my main activity thread. How can I stop this and make sure the code is run in my asynctask thread?

```
    textViewAll.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
            new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                @SuppressLint("NewApi")
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {

                                //My code occurs here

                }
            });
```

Comment: Start `AsyncTask` in `onGlobalLayout` method. and explain more what problem getting using current code

Comment: Wait, so start another asynctask in the ongloballayout method, even though this code is being run inside the asynctask I would like to use?

Comment: The problem is that I run some long operation stuff in this ongloballayout method and the fact that the code is running on the ui thread is causing the ui to freeze up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I stop this and make sure the code is run in my asynctask
>   thread?

Create a inner class by extending `AsyncTask` and move all code with is doing *long operation stuff*  in `doInBackground` method and if want to update UI elements according to result of long operation stuff then return result from `doInBackground` and get it in `onPostExecute` method.

Just call `AsyncTask.execute()` in `onGlobalLayout` method.